# Is there a way to change the color of a specific text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm on a site where I wanted to change my username color with `javascript`. I was able to change the background with `getElementById` but i cant seem to change the color of specific text without changing the whole page text color. Is there a way to use `getElementById` to change a specific text on the page?

Comment: What code did you have that you thought should have changed the text color? (edit your post, adding with what you tried so far)

Comment: [**HERE IT IS**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5TZk/2/)

Comment: you wanna clear answer, give demo in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.color = "red";
```

**DEMO**: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4qZc/)**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply have each username enclosed within a `<div>` tag with an id of that user's id. And reference it that way with `document.getElementById(). style.color`

Answer (score 0):

**[See this demo](http://jsbin.com/eketag/1/edit)**

```
<div> This div <span id="sp1">elements</span> have <span id="sp2">different</span> colours    </div>

document.getElementById('sp1').style.color = 'green';
document.getElementById('sp2').style.color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById only gets the whole HTML element which contain the specific ID. So if you wish to style on the specific bunch of text inside that element, you can use `inline elements` for the specific text. For example:

```
<div id="text">
  Some text with <span>your name</span> here.
</div>
```

Simply use CSS to style it rather than JavaScript:

```
div#text span {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: So i cant use javascript to do it?

Comment: Try not using JavaScript in something that CSS could do. Imagine if your javascript does not load or is prevented from loading, then your style will lose.

Comment: Yes i realize this, i dont want this color to be persistent. On the other hand it is not my site, im sorry for not being clear about that earlier

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only if you have the text wrapped by a node. Use span tag to contain the desire text. Include a class for the span like this `<span class="username">user name here</span>`. Then use in your CSS stylesheet :

> `span.username{`
>
> > `color : your.desired.color ;`
>
> `}`

I recommend you learn CSS if you are making a site. Is the best! If you don't want to use CSS you can just write `<span style="color:red">user name here</span>`. It will display the user name in red.